# How to see #default_values in multiselect form

Tags: forms

I've done a custom form that is a multiselect type form. When I edit the node, the options that were previously selected are not shown in the selected options part.

This is the code that I've done:

```
 foreach ($node->field_tem_tica[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $delta => $value) {
    $term2 = taxonomy_term_load($value['tid']);
 }

  $query2 = "SELECT name, tid FROM taxonomy_term_data WHERE vid=4 AND language = '$language_url';";
  $result = db_query($query2);
  foreach ($result as $row2) {
     $options3[$row2->tid] = t($row2->name);
  }

  $form['group_config']['tematicas'] = array(
     '#type' => 'multiselect',
     '#title' => t('Temáticas'),
     '#options' => $options3,
     '#required' => TRUE,
     '#multiple'=>TRUE,
     '#default_value'=> $term2,
     '#prefix' => '<p><br>',
     '#suffix' => '</p>',
     '#size'=>20,
  );
```

Does anybody see a mistake? Is there any way to see the default_values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value needs to be the *key* of the options array, so assuming the rest of your code is correct, this should work:

```
$form['group_config']['tematicas'] = array(
  '#type' => 'multiselect',
  '#title' => t('Temáticas'),
  '#options' => $options3,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#multiple'=>TRUE,
  '#default_value'=> $term2->tid,
  '#prefix' => '<p><br>',
  '#suffix' => '</p>',
  '#size'=>20,
);
```